# Who first discovered the concept corresponding to the symbol of class comprehension?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ho.history-overview, notation

Who first discovered the concept corresponding to the symbol of class comprehension 
 $\{x/\varphi\}$ used today in set theory ?

Comment: Was... that symbol introduced even before it was associated to a clear concept? I don't find the title or the question very clearly phrased

Comment: Isn’t “the concept corresponding to the symbol of class comprehension” just “class comprehension”?

Comment: For what it's worth, the history of set-builder notation itself might be interesting - I can't find much about it after a quick google search.

Comment: However you make this precise, van Heijenoort’s Source Book in Mathematical Logic is a good place to look.

Comment: I completely agree with Emil Jerabek and Noah Schweber, that my question is really about the history of the notion of class comprehension and of the set-builder notation.  Gérard Lang

Comment: You could ask the same thing without the symbol as "Who first discovered the concept of class comprehension used today in set theory?". This would make it clearer that there are multiple set theories to consider (ZFC, NBG, MK, NF), with different accounts of class comprehension. So we also shouldn't expect to find identical concepts in the theories like Zermelo's or Russell's or Frege's that were current when these ideas were more novel.

Comment: You may also ask history-related questions at [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concept is found with different notation in **Peano** ([1894](//zbmath.org/?q=an:25.0103.03), p. 20) (translated):

> Let $p_x$ be a proposition containing a variable letter $x$, that is, a condition on $x$. By the notation $\overline{x\ \varepsilon}\,p_x$ we shall indicate the class of those $x$ that satisfy the condition $p_x$.

Von Neumann ([1923](//zbmath.org/?q=an:49.0139.02), Einleitung) uses $M$ for *Menge*:

> Let $E(x)$ be a property, $f(x)$ a function defined for all $x$ possessing the property $E(x)$. Then
>   $$
> M(f(x); E(x))
> $$
>   shall be the set of all $f(x)$ as $x$ runs over all $x$ possessing the property $E(x)$.

Our *notation* $\{\ ..\mid\,...\}$ is in e.g. **Lefschetz** ([1942](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=7093), p. 2; [1949](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=31708), p. 26; ...), Iwasawa ([1945](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=31772); [1949](//mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=29911); ...), Segal ([1946](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=19218); [1947](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=19617); ...), Kelley ([1947](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=22999); [1953](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=54175); [1955](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=70144)), Mostow ([1949](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=32656); [1950](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=48464); ...), Yamabe ([1950](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=36766)), Nomizu ([1950](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=38354); [1954](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=64057); ...), Godement ([1952](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=44529); ...), Loomis ([1953](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=54173); ...), etc. Kelley ([1947](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=21315), p. 683) seems to attribute it to Lefschetz; Bernays ([1958](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=106178), § I.1) writes:

> Our logical symbols are (...)
>
> 3) The class operator $\{\mathfrak r\mid\mathfrak{A(r)}\}$<sup>1)</sup>  « the class of the $\mathfrak r$ such that $\mathfrak{A(r)}$ »
>
> (...)
>
> The rules concerning the class terms are: the formula schema (“Church schema”)
>   $$
> c\in\{\mathfrak r\mid\mathfrak{A(r)}\}\ \leftrightarrow\ \mathfrak A(c),
> $$
>   expressing a conversion law, in the sense of A. Church ([1932](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1503059)), and (...)
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1) This symbol (used in some newer papers) is here taken, for the sake of easier print, instead of Russell’s class symbol $\hat{\mathfrak r}\mathfrak{A(r)}$, whose adoption was first intended.</sup>

---

Added: Bernays’ *name* ***class operator*** for $\{\ ..\mid\,...\}$ came after Kelley’s ***classifier*** ([1955](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=70144), p. 251); [***set-builder***](//hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/where-did-the-term-set-builder-notation-come-from) seems to originate earlier in collective program books like *Universal Mathematics* ([1955](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=mdp.39015017411003&seq=26), p. I-9), *Concepts and Structure of Mathematics* ([1954](//books.google.com/books?id=juRQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22set+builder%22), p. 117) and *Fundamental Mathematics* ([1948](//books.google.com/books?id=aUE_AQAAIAAJ&q=%22the+set-builder%22), p. 24) — the latter however using the different notation $\underset{\textstyle{..}}{\mathrm S}\,...$

Comment: Surely the concept of comprehension was already known to Cantor?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek ... or to Euler, who drew a “space” to depict what any notion “[comprises](//mathoverflow.net/a/117063)”. I guess it depends how much explicitness we require. According to Ferreirós ([2007](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2348484), pp. 250-252), “Dedekind relied on the idea that every concept determines a set, but (...) did not formulate the principle of comprehension. His approach to sets remained as vague as those we find in Cantor
([1895/97](//zbmath.org/?q=an:28.0061.08)) or Schröder ([1890/95](//zbmath.org/?q=an:26.0074.01), vol. 1).”

Comment: (cont’d:) “It is sometimes said that Frege was the first to formulate in a precise form the principle of comprehension, with the basic law V of the *Grundgesetze*. However, as we shall see (...) that law was nothing but a principle of extensionality, while comprehension was implicit in the very notation employed by Frege. Thus, it seems that nobody pinned down the crucial principle of comprehension before the emergence of the paradoxes.”

Answer (score 3):

Following G.Cantor ( see ["Beiträge zur Begründung der transfiniten Mengenlehre" [*Contributions to the founding of the theory of transfinite numbers*], *Mathematische Annalen* (1895)](https://books.google.it/books?id=aagYb7FgeAMC&pg=PA85) ),the use of braces for sets was already present in E.Zermelo, [“Untersuchungen über die Grundlagen der Mengenlehre,” *Mathematische Annalen* (1908)](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA199) :

> The set that contains only the elements $a, b, c, \ldots, r$ will often be denoted briefly by $\{ a, b, c, \ldots, r\}$.

The modern symbol for sets defined "via comprehension" evolved from Whitehead & Russell's [Principia Mathematica (910-1913)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&p=PR39) :

> $\hat x (\phi x)$,

meaning : the class of individuals satisfying the propositional function $\phi x$.

As referred in the answer above, Paul Bernays, in [Axiomatic Set Theory (1958)](https://books.google.it/books?id=IopfGCCME6wC) says (page 46) :

> The class operator $\{ \mathfrak x \mid \mathfrak A (\mathfrak x) \}$ «the class of the $\mathfrak x$ such that $\mathfrak A (\mathfrak x)$» [*footnote* : This symbol (used in some newer papers) is here taken, for the sake of easier print, instead of Russell's class symbol $\hat {\mathfrak x} \ \mathfrak A (\mathfrak x)$, whose adoption was first intended.]

The symbol were not used by Bernays in his previous work published in the [*Journ. of Symb. Log*. (1937-1954)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2268862?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

---

*Note* : W&R's $\hat x$-notation for class-abstraction was also the source for Church's $\lambda$-notation.

See Alonzo Church,[A Set of Postulates for the Foundation of Logic (1932)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968337?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) :

> If $\text M$ is any formula containing the variable $x$, then $\lambda x [ \text M ]$ is the symbol for the function whose values are those given by the formula.

See Felice Cardone & J.Roger Hindley, [History of lambda-calculus and combinatory logic (2006)](http://www.users.waitrose.com/%7Ehindley/SomePapers_PDFs/2006CarHin,HistlamRp.pdf) :

> By the way, why did Church choose the notation “$\lambda$”? In Church (1964) [unpublished letter] he stated clearly that it came from the notation “$\hat x$” used for class-abstraction by Whitehead and Russell, by first modifying “$\hat x$” to “$\land x$” to distinguish function abstraction
> from class-abstraction, and then changing “$\land$” to “$\lambda$” for ease of printing.

See also : J.B. Rosser, [Highlights of the history of the lambda calculus, *Annals of the History of Computing* (1984)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4640786), page 338.

---

---

IMO, the symbol slowly emerged during the 1950s.

Lefschez's [Algebraic Topology (1942)](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/lefsch2.pdf) has it (page 2) :

> If $P$ is a property, the totality of all the elements $x$ which satisfy $P$ is denoted by $\{ x \mid x \text { has the property } P \}$.

Well-know set-theorists like A.Fraenkel do not used it; see Abraham Fraenkel, [Abstract Set Theory (1953)](https://books.google.it/books?id=UfNLAAAAMAAJ) and Abraham Fraenkel & Yehoshua Bar-Hillel, [Foundations of Set Theory (1958)](https://books.google.it/books?id=JJF-QwAACAAJ).

But P.Suppes in [Axiomatic set theory (1960)](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) says (page 33) :

> In many branches of modern mathematics it is customary to use the notation:
>
> > $\{ x : \varphi(x) \}$
>
> to designate the set of all objects having the property $\varphi$.

Bourbaki's Theory of sets (1968) has

> $\mathcal E_x(R)$ [for the term denoting] "the set of all $x$ such that $R$".

The 1970 second French edition has instead :

> le symbole $\{x \mid R \}$ [par] «l'ensemble des $x$ tels que $R$».

Comment: Why do you believe that the source of Church's $\lambda x. \phi(x)$ was W&R's  $\hat{x}.\phi(x)$? Does Church say so somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold There are some references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Origin_of_the_lambda_symbol .

Comment: Interesting. Is there any evidence that W&R got the inspiration for their $\hat{x}.\phi(x)$ from Frege's $\grave x \phi(x)$, found in _Funktion und Begriff_, 1891?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold - yes; added ref.

Comment: And yes; the origin is with Frege's symbol $`\epsilon ϕ(\epsilon)$ for [Wertverlauf](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#2.1).